# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xef'

Tags: python, ascii, encode

I am scrapping Amazon customer review.  It runs a while but after certain point, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "custreviewscrap.py", line 73, in <module>
    strcomment = str(k.getText())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xef' in position 293
7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried following things but didn't work...

```
1)strcomment = `str(k.getText()).encode('utf8')`
2)strcomment = str(k.getText())
  strcomment = strcomment.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Thank you very much!

```
for k in bsreview2.findAll('div',{"style":"margin-left:0.5em;"}):
    #next part is clean the comments. sorry, this part is really dirty, I should have written a function
    #the comment is surrounded by different stuff depends on what kind of review it is, video or pics or text
    strcomment = str(k.getText())
    patcomment = re.compile(r'(.*(\(Electronics\)|\(Health and Beauty\)))')
    patcomment2 = re.compile(r'Help other customers find.*')
    patcomment3 = re.compile(r'(Customer review from the Amazon Vine Program(.|\n)*Length::)|(\<\!(.|\n)*Length::)|(Customer review from the Amazon Vine Program\(What\'s this\?\)|(.*See all my reviews))')

    cleancomment = re.sub(patcomment, '', strcomment)
    cleancomment = re.sub('&nbsp;', '', cleancomment)
    cleancomment = re.sub(patcomment2, '', cleancomment)
    cleancomment = re.sub(',' ,'.', cleancomment)
    cleancomment = re.sub(patcomment3, '', cleancomment)
    strdate = str(k.nobr.getText())
    cleandate = re.sub(',','',strdate)

    print (k.span.getText())[0:1]+','+ cleandate +',' + cleancomment
    csvtext = csvtext + (k.span.getText())[0:1]+','+ cleandate +',' + a +','+ cleancomment + '\n'
```

Comment: Looks like you are using Python?

Comment: So ... adding the tag for that could have been useful, no?

Comment: Could you please update the title, and add more tags to get better answers.

Comment: What is `k.getText` returning? Presumably it's already a string so why are you calling `str` on it?

Comment: I took out str but then get this error  2: illegal multibyte sequence

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `k.getText()` returns Unicode, the following would work (where `s` is the result of `k.getText()`):

```
>>> s = u'\xef'
>>> s.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xaf'
```

Note that a `str()` call isn't needed anymore.

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you very much for your reply.  

Is following correct?  I get syntax error with this..

>strcomment = k.getText()
>strcomment = u'\xef'
>strcomment.encode('utf-8')'\xc3\xaf'
               

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "custreviewscrap1.py", line 75
strcomment.encode('utf-8')'\xc3\xaf'
                                 ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Hi, I removed '\xc3\xaf' part and set the first 2 sentenses and now looks OK but got the same sort of error as following.  How should I modify for here?  Thanks for your kind advise!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "custreviewscrap1.py", line 88, in <module>
    print (k.span.getText())[0:1]+','+ cleandate +',' + cleancomment
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp932' codec can't encode character u'\xef' in position 18:
 illegal multibyte sequence

Comment: @user2784364 I think it's the same as previously: you need to encode the output of `k.span.getText()` first before doing anything else with it.

Comment: @user2784364, specifically you need to encode it with the proper parameters: `((k.span.getText())[0:1]+','+ cleandate +',' + cleancomment).encode(sys.stdout.encoding, 'replace')`